# Pointer Declaration Equivalency

Tags: c, pointers

`char *charPtr = malloc(50);`

`char *charPtr; *charPtr = malloc(50);`

I have been creating pointers in C like the examples above. Is it okay to say that these two are the same in C?

Comment: They are not the same, does it compile without warnings?

Comment: You have an extra `*` in the second assignment.  Change it to `charPtr = malloc(50);` then they will be equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it okay to say that these two are the same in C?

No, you need to either **initialize** the pointer.

```
char *charPtr = malloc(50);  // initialization
```

Or, you **declare** it first, then **assign** it later:

```
char *charPtr;  // declaration
charPtr = malloc(50);  // <-- assignment - do NOT add * here as the you already declared `charPtr` as a pointer
```

Note that doing it like you did (2nd case) was wrong:

```
char *charPtr; 
*charPtr = malloc(50);  // <-- WRONG, the * here is deference operator
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same. In this case

```
char *charPtr;
*charPtr = malloc(50);
```

You are

1. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer and that would cause *Undefined Behavior*.
2. Assigning a pointer to an integer of different size without casting. Although conversion from pointer to integer and the other way is defined according to the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard, there are some things you should consider. If this code has been working for you it's because of *Undefined Behavior* mentioned above. You never know that it's happening until something bad happens which might happen all the time or never, or sometimes, you really never know.

The `*` plays two different roles here, in the first case

```
char *charPtr;
```

it simply indicates that `charPtr` is a pointer, whereas in

```
*charPtr = malloc(50);
```

it's the dereference operator.

Of course, the `*` is also the multiplication operator but it's interpretation by the compiler depends on the context where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

No. The first declares `charPtr` as a pointer to `char`, and it contains the return value of `malloc`.

The second declares `charPtr` as a pointer to `char`. It then says that the value `charPtr` points to should be set to the return value of `malloc`. This is wrong. The pointer is uninitialized, and to say what it should point at is undefined behavior. In addition, assigning a `void *` to a `char` should generate a compiler diagnostic.

Comment: Both are not just declarations, but also definitions.

Comment: What's the difference? @iharob

Comment: @stackptr A pointer to `char` sounds like it's pointing to the type `char`. I don't know, just doesn't sound right.

Comment: K&R uses that type of language @iharob

Comment: @stackptr That doesn't mean that it should sound right. It's of course just my opinion.